# How to reach Martial Arts Club: Central?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

I've been wasting loads of time trying to figure out how to get to this on my map. I wasn't fussed but now I have a favour there also and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get up to it.

The spot is opposite Rolands Garage.
[image]

There is an art gallery to the east of the parking, but no way to go up inside.

Comment: [The first rule of Fight Club is...](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137523/quotes?qt0479119)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Irony strikes, I found it as soon as I posted this question. On the far west end of the greyed out path are a set of closed blue double doors. These you can run through and up the stairs.
[image]